# SQL using XMLAGG function is not retrieving results while executing in Java

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have been trying to execute an Oracle SQL query using java program through JDBC connectivity.
In the SQL query, I am using XMLAGG function.

Below is the sample of the query that is similar to what I use:

```
SELECT XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,ename||',')).EXTRACT('//text()') "Result" FROM `employee_names`
```

The result is supposed to be as shown below:

```
Result

-------------------------------------------------------------------

SMITH,ALLEN,WARD,JONES,MARTIN,BLAKE,CLARK,SCOTT,KING,TURNER,ADAMS
```

When I execute this query using a Java program, I am getting `null` for that column value.

If anyone faced similar issue and resolved it, please let me know the solution.

Thanks
Marshal

Answer (score 0):

[XMLAGG](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions215.htm) returns an aggregated XML document. Did your program use `xdb6.jar` to parse the document? If not, then retrieval would have hit into `XMLParseException` when XML document is retrieved as string.

The best workaround would be to use `getstringval()` method of `XMLAGG` to retrieve the values as string.

So, your updated query string will look like the following:

```
String qry = "SELECT XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,ename||',')).EXTRACT('//text()').getstringval()" +
             " FROM employee_names";
```

Following sample program worked fine at my end:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class XMLAggTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Connection con=null;
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:hr/hr@myhost:1521:bct01");
            if(con != null)
            {
                String upq="SELECT XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,first_name||',')).EXTRACT('//text()').getstringval()" +
                           " FROM employees";


                PreparedStatement pStat;
                try {
                    pStat = con.prepareStatement(upq);
                    ResultSet rSet = pStat.executeQuery();
                    while(rSet.next()){
                        System.out.println(rSet.getString(1));
                    }
                    rSet = null;
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                pStat = null;

            }
            con.close();

        } catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```